# Process builder with Interactive session for Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, windows-runtime, runtime, processbuilder

I am using process builder to execute the postgres commands using Java code in command prompt.

Below is the piece of code which i am using currently. Here the problem is the code keep on hangs/wait since the password needs to be entered. Postgres database doesn't have a feature to enter the password in the same command.

Is there anyway to use the process builder in interactive mode in same session ?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String path = "E\\test.csv";
    String command = "psql -h 127.0.0.1 -d incremental_db -U postgres -c " + "\"" + "\\copy test_table (ID)  from '"
            + path + "' with delimiter as ','" + "\"";

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = rt.exec(command);
    OutputStream writeTo = p.getOutputStream();
    writeTo.write("password\n".getBytes());
    writeTo.flush();
    writeTo.close();

    int code = p.waitFor();
    System.out.println(code);



}
```